# NAO Robot Optimized access to images tutorial

Tags: c++, nao-robot

I was just wondering if anyone had used the "Optimized access to images" example from the tutorial section of the naoqi help pages?

http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/dev/cpp/examples/vision/optimizedimage/optimizedimage.html

i can get the code to compile and create the module in naoqi but I am at a loss on how to use it. none of the functions are callable and the only instruction on how to use the module is: "To retrieve the images, subscribe as usual using a proxy to ALVideoDevice, and specify the framerate, resolution etc."

All examples for retrieving images have the line: ALValue img = camProxy.getImageRemote(clientName); which does not seem to go through the optimization routine.

my question is , how do i use the optimization module in my main c++ code?

Answer (score 0):

There's no bound method: 
the idea is to personnalize the "optimizedImage module" by putting your processing at this place: "/** Do whatever processing you want... */"

And then after your processing, depending of your architecture, you can decide to post results in ALMemory, or to bind your own method in your "optimizedModule" to give services to your own application.

By the way: it looks strange to me, that giving you just a pointer to an image in another process (as you're in remote, it means it's not your process) give you the permission to read the data.

A such system would haveno control of what every process can access, and so it seems very bizarre nowadays. (as some old MS DOS system)

I remember having done that kind of code on NAO from a python code to acquire an image, but then I was in the same memory space (ALPythonBridge) and so can read and interpret the raw image.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, just to clarify at what point does the  optimizedImage code run/get the image(or the pointer to)? is it when the call to:ALTools::mainFunction("optimizedimage", argc, argv, sig); is made or at some other point? I tried a cout in the "/*do whatever.." section of the code to test this (should print a message on the remote computer unless i am mistaken) but nothing seemed to happen.

Comment: Just as a note i put cout statements in the OptimizedImage::init section of the code and these statements do print on the remote computer when I run the optimizedImage code, it is only the cout in the image processing section that does not run.